# How can I make Ubuntu recognize 2 different speaker pairs through an audio splitter?

Tags: 10.04, sound

I have 2 different pairs of speakers (one with a sub, one without) that both connect to standard TRS connectors. My laptop only has one female jack, so I purchased an audio splitter like the one below in order to use both. How can I make Ubuntu recognize that there are two different speaker devices plugged in, in order to change the balance on them through the Sound Preferences?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Most splitters simply forward the same audio to both speakers (or headphones as is my case). Even if your splitter could do more than that, there is no way for the audio device in your computer to send out two separate stereo streams.

What you need is a different audio device, maybe a 4.0 or 5.1 usb sound card.